# How to open an app side by side in winrt 8.1 and pass context?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

In Windows **8.1**, I've seen video demonstrating that app can now cause a second, separate app to start, running side-by-side split screen.  I would like to know what is the API to do this?

I also need to pass in some context at the time the other app is invoked.  We have a set of app that will work together and we need this seamless integration.  Internet might be unavailable, so web services aren't an option.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is **WinRT XAML / C#** BTW.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to set `LauncherOptions.DesiredRemainingView` per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464906.aspx) to one of the enumeration values specifying how much of the screen you'd like to keep for your application.

Due to the sandboxed model of Windows Store apps, sharing data isn't as simple. There are several options that may work for you: [contracts and extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464906.aspx) and a [custom url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701480.aspx)([walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779672.aspx)).